# Merging laravel request params with array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get laravel-scout tntsearch with eloquent's query builder, this has proven difficult so my current approach is to first use tntsearch to get results, pluck ids from the results adn then add a wherIn clause with the plucked ids, to do this I have an additional class QueryFilters to sort and filter in a composable way.

Issue is I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to undefined method App\Filters\QueryFilters::merge()
```

Here is my code:

```
public function search(Request $request, QueryFilters $filters)
    {
        //Search with tntsearch 
        $posts = Post::search($request->input('search'))->get();

        //Grab ids and prepare to merge with $filters
        $postIds = $posts->pluck('id');
        $toMerge = collect(['whereIn' => $postIds]);

        $filters->merge($toMerge);
        //Filter and sort results
        $posts = Post::filter($filters)->with(['postcategory','author','favorites'])->paginate(10);
}
```

How QueryFilters works is iterating throught the request object looking for methods with the same name and returning each time an instance of the query builder.

```
<?php
namespace App\Filters;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class QueryFilters
{
    protected $request;
    protected $builder;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function title($term)
    {
        $lowerCaseTerm = strtolower($term);

        return $this->builder->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$lowerCaseTerm%");
    }

    public function postCategory($term)
    {
        if($term == 0)
        {
            return $this->builder->whereHas('postcategory', function ($query) use ($term){
                $query->where('id', '>', 0);
            });
        }

        return $this->builder->whereHas('postcategory', function ($query) use ($term){
            $query->where('id', $term);
        });
    }

    public function sortBy($term)
    {
        $sortArray = explode(",", $term);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($sortArray); $i++)
        {
            $sortBy = substr_replace($sortArray[$i], "", -1);

            $sortChar = substr($sortArray[$i], -1);

            $sortOrder = $sortChar == '+' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';  

            $this->builder->orderBy($sortBy, $sortOrder);
        }

        return $this->builder;
    }

    public function whereIn($postIds)
    {
        return $this->builder->whereIn('id', $postIds);
    }

    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $this->builder = $builder;
        foreach ($this->filters() as $name => $value)
        {
            //if method doesn't exists continue out of the loop 
            if ( ! method_exists($this, $name))
            {
                continue;
            }
            //method exists so check if it has a value payload so call the method with arguments
            if (strlen($value)) 
            {
                $this->$name($value);
            } 
            //it doesn't have a payload so call the method without arguments
            else 
            {
                $this->$name();
            }
        }
        return $this->builder;
    }

    public function filters()
    {
        //returns associative array of request body key value pairs
        return $this->request->all();
    }

}
```

To know more about this class see this medium article:
https://medium.com/@mykeels/writing-clean-composable-eloquent-filters-edd242c82cc8

If I dd $filters I get this:

```
QueryFilters {#457
  #request: Request {#43
    #json: null
    #convertedFiles: null
    #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#421
      class: "Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider"
      this: AuthServiceProvider {#41 …}
      use: {
        $app: Application {#2 …}
      }
      file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\dog-media.es\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider.php"
      line: "83 to 85"
    }
    #routeResolver: Closure() {#423
      class: "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      this: Router {#26 …}
      use: {
        $route: Route {#220 …}
      }
      file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\dog-media.es\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php"
      line: "650 to 652"
    }
    +attributes: ParameterBag {#45
      #parameters: []
    }
    +request: ParameterBag {#51
      #parameters: array:3 [
        "loaderId" => "1111"
        "postCategory" => "0"
        "sortBy" => "created_at+"
      ]
    }
    +query: ParameterBag {#51}
    +server: ServerBag {#47

...
```

And my Filter scope:

```
<?php
namespace App\Filters;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait Filterable
{
    public function scopeFilter($query, QueryFilters $filters)
    {
        return $filters->apply($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to add `merge()` method to `QueryFilters`. Something like this `public function merge(array $params) { $this->request->merge($params)}`

Comment: I get Argument 2 passed to App\Models\Post::scopeFilter() must be an instance of App\Filters\QueryFilters, null given

Comment: Can you add your `scopeFilter` definition? Is it defined in the trait or in `Post`?